# the import org.openqa.selenium.webdriver cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, java-8, webdriver

[image]

I have added these jar files as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to use Maven?

Comment: @user6914996 Snapshot of _JDK_ binaries please...

Comment: Remove the selenium jars that you have added and download selenium jar via link : http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/. Add the downloaded selenium jar to the project to identify the interface `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver` and class `org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver`

Answer (score 1):

Try to Clean the project by using Menu -> Project -> Clean
Cross check if selenium server jars file are added under Build path -> configure build path -> java build path -> library.

You can also refer - https://www.selenium.dev/docs/site/en/selenium_installation/
Note - seleniumhq.org is now selenium.dev

Answer (score 0):

> Either keep only selenium-server-standalone-3.141. jar as an external JAR.
> Or keep only selenium-java-3.141 Remove all the other Selenium Java Client JARs. Clean your Project Workspace through your IDE and Rebuild your project with required dependencies only.